# Style components for React and Angular JS

Tags: css, angularjs, user-interface, reactjs

How is it possible to style UI components so they work with both, Angular JS and React? Both technologies will be used together for the same app.

Answer (score 0):

It is not matter of  a framework. 
If you write your html code, along with classes and ids, the same, you wont have problem applying css to any framework.

Same structure (id, class) is the key.

And also, you can separate css code to individual components, or write it in one css file

Answer (score 0):

Good question!

I think that UI Style is job of art-team, and front-end chooses framework which is react or angular to develop.

If you want to design UIcomponent all in one, I'm saying "No", becasue  react and angular have very different part.

For example as follows:

1.react component can be writed .JSX

2.angular always use ng-xxx attribute in the components

Comment: The thing is that both technologies (Angular and React) will be used in the same project. And I was told that the same components will get used from both sides.

Comment: You can only design react component and use that [Use React Components in Angular](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact)